# odbc_execute(): supplied resource is not a valid ODBC result resource using PHP

Tags: php, oracle, apache

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database with PHP. This is how my code currently looks:

```
$user = "myuser"; 
$password = "myuser";
$con = odbc_connect("Driver={Devart ODBC driver for Oracle};Direct=true;Host=host;Port=1521;Service Name=serv;User ID=myuser;Password=myuser", $user, $password);

$insercion = "INSERT INTO `table` (`attr1`, `attr2`, `attr3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
**$rs = odbc_execute($con, array($attr1, $attr2, $attr3));**

if($rs)
    echo "Inserted";
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: odbc_execute(): supplied resource is not a valid ODBC result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\ddsi\server\funciones.php on line 63

Line 63 is the one between ** in the code above. Am I missing something? This whole Oracle thing seems a mess... Thanks in advance!

**Additional Info**

I've created a new System DSN under OBDC Data Sources (32 bits). When clicking "Test Connection" it says "Connection successful".

Doing `var_dump($con);` shows the following:

> resource(5) of type (odbc link)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this old question while searching for another problem. So I thought I might as well reply to it.

As you're using parameters in a prepared statement, you can't omit the `odbc_prepare` part of the code. This should be fine:

```
$user = "myuser"; 
$password = "myuser";
$con = odbc_connect("Driver={Devart ODBC driver for Oracle};Direct=true;Host=host;Port=1521;Service Name=serv;User ID=myuser;Password=myuser", $user, $password);

$insercion = "INSERT INTO `table` (`attr1`, `attr2`, `attr3`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = odbc_prepare($con, $insercion);
$rs = odbc_execute($stmt, array($attr1, $attr2, $attr3));

if($rs)
    echo "Inserted";
```